# Injecting css to a window.document when using react portal

Tags: reactjs, styling, portal

I'm using react portal to present a printable version of my react view. This is what I do:

```
import { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export default class PortalWindow extends Component {
  container = document.createElement("div");
  externalWindow = null;

  componentDidMount() {
    this.externalWindow = window.open();
    this.externalWindow.document.body.appendChild(this.container);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.externalWindow.close();
  }

  render() {
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(this.props.children, this.container);
  }
}

import React from 'react';
import './order-print.css';
function OrderPrint(props) {

  return (
    <div className="order-print">

    </div>
  );
}
export default OrderPrint;
```

And there's a component called PurchaseOrder where I do the following:

```
class PurchaseOrder extends React.Component {
...//omitted for brevity  
render(){
          {this.state.shouldPrint && (
            <PortalWindow>
              <OrderPrint order={order} />
            </PortalWindow>
          )}
  }
}
```

So with a click of a button, I change the `shouldPrint` state to true and the printable version is displayed in a new window. However, the `import './order-print.css';`  statement seems to have no effect, so the style is not applied to the div that's in my OrderPrint.jsx file.

Here's the content of the `order-print.css` file:

```
.order-print{
  border:3 px solid red;
}
```

So apparently, react does not pass the css to the view that's loaded in a new window. Is there a way to make this possible.

I've actually tried using `style` instead of `className` and referencing a const object that has styling information, and in fact, it works. but it's just I prefer using classes to inline styling.

Comment: have you resolved this issue? if so, could you please share it @Mikayil

Answer (score 1):

Something like this worked for me:

```js
    componentDidMount() {
        this.externalWindow = window.open();

        // find the existing style tags in the parent window
        const styleTagsInHead = window.document.head.getElementsByTagName("style");

        // clone them
        const styles = Array.from(styleTagsInHead).map(style => style.cloneNode());

        // and add them to the new child window
        this.externalWindow.document.head.append(...styles);
        
        this.externalWindow.document.body.appendChild(this.container);
    }
```

**Note!**
You may need to change how you query for the style tags depending on how styling is applied in your application.