# How to load a html form in an iframe

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to know how to load the HTML form in the iframe in reactjs.

I have one form component that has all the input fields, and I want to load that form component in the iframe. I would like to know how I can do that.

```
const Form = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <iframe name="iframe-form" title="This is an iframe form." />
    <form target="iframe-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="name"
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" />
      </div>
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
</>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

Currently, it's rendering like this.
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to host this form somewhere and use an absolute path of it in an iframe?

Comment: No, it's a part of the project, so I can't host it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set iframe content of a react component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34743264/how-to-set-iframe-content-of-a-react-component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the React documentation, '**React Portals**' allow us to render children into a DOM node that exists outside of the parent component’s DOM hierarchy. Basically, [portals let us render children](https://blog.logrocket.com/learn-react-portals-example/) wherever we want to.

So the large explanation would be create a portal:

```
ReactDOM.createPortal(child, container)
```

> In this case, the child is a React **element**, **fragment**, or **string**, and the container is the `DOM` location or node to which the portal should be rendered.
>
> > With a React portal, we can choose where to place a DOM node in the DOM hierarchy, the portal’s contents are also considered children of the parent’s **virtual DOM**.

**MyComponent.js**

```js
import React from 'react'

function MyComponent() {
    return (
        <div>
            <p style={{color: 'red'}}>Testing to see if my component renders!</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Now, let’s create a file called **CustomIframe.js** and write the following code:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom'

const CustomIframe = ({
  children,
  ...props
}) => {
  const [contentRef, setContentRef] = useState(null)

  const mountNode =
    contentRef?.contentWindow?.document?.body

  return (
    <iframe {...props} ref={setContentRef}>
      {mountNode && createPortal(children, mountNode)}
    </iframe>
  )
}

export default CustomIframe;
```

> We created a ref with the `useState()` Hook, therefore, once the state is updated, the component will re-render.
>
> > We also got access to the iframe document body, then created a portal to render the children **passed to iframe in this body** instead:

```
import './App.css';
import CustomIframe from './CustomIframe';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';
function App() {


  return (
    <CustomIframe title='A custom made iframe'>
        <MyComponent />
      </CustomIframe>
  );
}

export default App;
```

You can pass any React app or component as a child of `CustomIframe`, and it should work fine.

The React app or component will become **encapsulated**, meaning you can develop and maintain it independently.

> You can also achieve the same encapsulation as above using a library called react frame component. To install it, run the following command:

```terminal
npm install --save react-frame-component
```

Encapsulate your component as follows:

```js
import Frame from 'react-frame-component';

function App() {

  return (
    <div className='App'>
        <p>Iframes in React</p>
        <Frame >
           <MyComponent />
        </Frame>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: This worked, but now my Form component styling doesn’t get applied. Any idea how to fix that? I tried to import the `App.css` file in the Form component directly, but it still didn’t work.

Comment: That is because we could use the `srcdoc` attribute, which takes in an inline HTML to embed, however we’re then trying to render an entire app or component, with uses extensive and verbose code, so I would recommend find a way to render the component in the iframe body instead of as a child of it, and for that, we should use a portal. I find this similar [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57405409/injecting-css-to-a-window-document-when-using-react-portal) could fix your issue about styles.

Comment: The attached post doesn't have any answers.

Comment: I wanted to attach [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65991135/how-to-include-styles-in-react-create-portal) sorry, I can't edit the comment above anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ReactDOMServer.renderToString` with `iframe`'s `srcDoc` attribute.

```
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <iframe
        name="iframe-form"
        title="This is an iframe form."
        srcDoc={ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<Form />)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const Form = () => {
  return (
    <form target="iframe-form">
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" />
      </div>
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit react iframe with inline content]